# How override material ui style with hooks

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I try to create AppBar clipped to the page top and hovering over other Drawer with React Hooks and Material Ui using class name. All as described in: https://material-ui.com/demos/drawers/#clipped-under-the-app-bar

So we have

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
root: {
    display: 'flex',
    height: '100%',
},
drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
},
appBar: {
   zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
},
menuButton: {
    marginRight: 20,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
        display: 'none',
    },
},
```

}));

And reder:

```
     <div className={classes.root}>
                <CssBaseline/>
                <LoadingResults showLoading={showLoadingSpinner}/>
                <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar} >
                     ...
                </AppBar>
    ....
```

Problem is that the style applied with className is added last of the element so its not overriding the orignal style:

> class="MuiPaper-root-12 MuiPaper-elevation4-18 MuiAppBar-root-3 MuiAppBar-positionFixed-4 MuiAppBar-colorPrimary-10 mui-fixed **Hook-appBar-1b6f20g**"

I know I can use inline styles but wonder to know if I can override styles using classNames with hooks as it was with "legacy" component approach ?

Here is sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/w7njqorzy7?fontsize=14

What happens is that in sandbox the code works ok (appbar over lefthand side container)
[image]

But when the same project is downloaded and compiled it's not ok:
[image]

Looking at the debuger the styles are inline. 
In the sandbox hooks are at the bottom:

[image]

In the browser when app is run via "run start" its on top:

[image]

So this is the difference, but why  and how to fix this ?

Comment: The order of classes in the `class` property has no bearing on the resulting styles. The order that matters is the order in which the CSS class definitions occur (e.g. the order of the style elements `<style>...</style>`). Please show a CodeSandbox that reproduces the problem you are having.

Comment: I've upated it with sandbox. Turns out it works different in sandbox and not.

Comment: To use `@material-ui/styles` you need to perform the bootstrap step (https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/basics/#migration-for-material-ui-core-users)

Comment: Thank you @JoshWooding. I had this bootstrap file with new styles install but you comment made me look into it again. Turned out that it was imported after material ui components and it should be done as first thing.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that my bootstrap.js with new styles install was in wrong place.

```
import { install } from '@material-ui/styles';

install();
```

Should be executed before any material ui component is imported.

Answer (score 1):

You can override material-ui styles with `classes` props instead of `classNames`.

For example

```
<AppBar position="fixed" classes={{root: classes.appBar}}>
```

Here I have used `root` key to override, there are many other keys with which you can play around.

Every Material-ui component have an api section. You will get list of overriding keys listed there.

Some useful links -

[https://https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-class-names](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-class-names)

https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/

Comment: first url is broken

Answer (score 1):

https://material-ui.com/ru/styles/advanced/#makestyles

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {}, // a style rule
  label: {}, // a nested style rule
});

function Nested(props) {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return (
    <button className={classes.root}>
      <span className={classes.label}> // 'jss2 my-label'
        nested
      </span>
    </button>
  );
}

function Parent() {
  return <Nested classes={{ label: 'my-label' }} />
}
```